# How do I represent 10 objects' distances to every other object (in iterations)?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 10 objects (say tennis balls) of varying distances from each other, how do I represent each object's distance to all other objects in iterations?

(I'm sorry, I'm not much of a mathematician so I apologize in advance if I'm not being clear or using the correct words.)

Comment: I'm not sure what "in iterations" means. Are the balls in the plane? In space? Also you may want to think of a tag that fits -- (functions) certainly doesn't.

Comment: Can you give me a tag please? What I'm saying is say you have 10 tennis balls strewn about a tennis court on the ground. How would you represent the amount of distances (straight lines) from each tennis ball to each other tennis ball?

Comment: What do you mean the amount of distances from each tennis ball to each other? Between any two tennis balls there is exactly one straight line. Do you want the total number? And sure, I can tag it for you once I understand the question, no problem.

Comment: Okay. So there are 10 balls. Each ball has a relational distance from the other 9 balls. So let's say they are all numbered 1 to 10. Ball 1 will have a relational distance to balls 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10. How do I determine how many relational distances there are between each ball to the other balls in aggregate? I.e. - 2 --> 1, 2--> 3, 2 -->4 etc. i don't know how else to explain it. How many distance lines exist between each ball to every other ball and how is it written or determined?

Answer (score 0):

There are ${10 \choose 2}=45$ distances between the balls, which may not be all different.  You can choose the first ball in $10$ ways, the second in $9$ ways (because it can't be the same ball), but you have counted every pair twice because either ball could have been picked first.  $\frac {10 \cdot 9}2=45$.  You can number the balls $1$ to $10$ and define $d_{ij}$ as the distance from ball $i$ to $j$.  Then the fact that you can pick the pair in either order is represented by the fact that $d_{ij}=d_{ji}$

Comment: And it brings me to my next question. How would you represent that if there were 10^23 balls?

Comment: Mathematically, the same way.  The fact that there are lots of them is not an issue.  From a computation view, you have trouble.  That is why statistical mechanics was invented.  You can't even store the coordinates of $10^{23}$ balls.  Please ask the real question. I thought you were a beginner to combinatorics and clearly wasted my time.

Comment: I am a beginner and if I'm wasting your valuable time then go do something infinitely more important. Last time I come here...

Comment: Note to self: stay away from mathematicians - not at all a friendly bunch. Good day.

Comment: I have seen many cases where it started this way.  Somebody asked a question for a small set of data that was easy to handle, but was really thinking about a much bigger problem, then complained when it became intractable at larger scales.  The jump from $10$ to $10^{23}$ reminded me of that.  As I said, from a mathematical point of view, there is no difference.  $10$ or $10^{23}$ is still a finite list and there are a finite number of pairs to consider.  Yes, the second does not fit on my computer.  For $10^{23}$ balls there will be $\frac 12(10^{23}-1)10^{23}$ distances.

Comment: I thought if I got an answer to a small number I could determine the larger number but my skills just aren't that good yet.

Comment: The important thing is to see the logic of the calculation.  Given $n$ balls, you can pick the first in $n$ ways, the second in $n-1$ ways, then have to divide by $2$ because you can choose them in either order.  You are looking for the number of combinations-the number of ways to select $r$ items from a pool of $n$ when you don't care about the order you choose them in. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) has an article.  You could also look as questions here tagged combinatorics to see a range of related questions.